# how to include opencv dlls in order for exe to run

Tags: dll, opencv, exe

I am wondering how do I allow my OpenCV project exe file to run on other Windows 7 machines without modifying other pcs. It runs on mine as I have all the libs installed. Can I embed the necessary files into the folder with the exe file?

Answer (score 3):

You should create a folder ( `...project/libs`, for example), put the libraries in it and in VisualStudio (I guess you are using VS), in **Configuration Properties -> Linker -> General -> Additional Libraries Directories** set a relative path this way:

> "$(SolutionDir)\libs"

Where $(SolutionDir) is the path of your project. The environmet variable can be created in Control Panel -> System and Security -> System -> Advanced System Settings -> Environment Variables. Then just click New and add the path and the variable name ( SolutionDir).

Answer (score 2):

You can put all the needed dll's in the same folder as your exe, or put them in a different folder (let's say C:/Programs/OpenCV/bin) and add this path into the System PATH.

To set PATH, go to
My-Computer - Properties, Advanced system settings -> environment variables, and look for Path. Add yours, and do not forget to separate it with a ";".

Comment: i have put the dlls in the same folder as exe but i am getting error when i run exe on other laptop(which has no visual studio). the error is "failed to start application as configuration is not side by side"

Comment: Either you do not have all the dll's, or you need to install something else, like VS runtime library.

Comment: you can also check the missing dlls with depends.exe It is a small app that looks for the libraries needed by a program, and tells you which ones are missing.

Comment: does the computer i am trying to run the exe on have to have visual studio? i am trying to get this to run on any windows 7 computer or laptop

Comment: Don't forget to add the variable to the PATH!!!!!! :D